# Grails POST Rest service problem

Tags: rest, grails, controller

I have the following urlmappings:

```
"/loader/" {
  action = [POST:"savep"]
  controller = 'loader'
}
```

savep is:

```
def savep = {
    params.each {
    log.debug "p:" + it
}
```

The client is sending in the post data:

```
{"vars":"{\"E32\":\"0\",\"E33\":\"0\",\"E34 ... etc
```

But I can't read the data in the controller; all I get is:

```
2011-03-15 13:20:42,646 [http-8080-2] DEBUG Test.LoaderController  - p:action={POST=savep}
2011-03-15 13:20:42,647 [http-8080-2] DEBUG Test.LoaderController  - p:controller=loader
```

Any hints ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the request needs to be parsed, so in your mapping you need something like this:

```
"/loader/" (controller: "loader", parseRequest: true){
  action = [POST: "savep"]
}
```

You can find more information in the Grails documentation about [how to map to HTTP methods](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4.5%20Mapping%20to%20HTTP%20methods) and about [Web Services](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/13.%20Web%20Services.html) and the usage of parseRequest. There is also this other [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-grails09168/) about Grails and REST that could be useful.